Using environment variables in `/etc/php/8.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`
[www]

env[VAR_A]="A"
env[VAR_B]=$B       ; got "", expected "B"
env[VAR_C]=${C}     ; php8.2-fpm cannot start, no errors in /var/log/php8.2-fpm.log
env[VAR_D]="${D}"   ; php8.2-fpm cannot start, no errors in /var/log/php8.2-fpm.log
# env[VAR_E]="${E}" ; php8.2-fpm cannot start, no errors in /var/log/php8.2-fpm.log


I'm trying to configure some environment variables into PHP 8.2.
I expect to see the assigned values in PHP using $_SERVER, which I do for VAR_A.
Based on googling, I should also be able to read from the environment variables. But VAR_E is just straight up weird. Any ideas how I can read an environment variable?
